# I need to query a database based on keywords

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to query a postgresql database where there are keywords stored in the same row as the data I am trying to query.  If it is queried on that keyword, that object is more likely, but not guaranteed to be the object queried.  I want it to query about 10 items at a time, but I'm pretty sure I know how to do that(select top 10).  So basically if the keyword is present it is more likely but not guaranteed to be the object queried.  How do I do this?

I have a year of experience as a database developer but I don't know how to solve this problem.  I would also be open to switching software if there are better suggestions.  Thanks!!

So for example if the user searches on Apples then Data2 is more likely, but not guaranteed to be queried.

[image]

Comment: Please post some sample data and expected output.

Comment: Hi @AnkitBajpai,  sorry for the delay, does the above work?

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to select 10 rows, prefering those matching the keyword. So, order by match, then restrict to ten rows:

```
select *
from mytable
order by
  case when keyword1 = 'Apples' then 0 else 1 end + 
  case when keyword2 = 'Apples' then 0 else 1 end +
  case when keyword3 = 'Apples' then 0 else 1 end
fetch first 10 rows only;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=34758b94fe725f7f51a476e80c97187c

A row with a matching keyword is more likely, but not guaranteed to be selected, because the query picks ten rows, making arbitrary choices in case of ties. The linked demo shows one situation with less than 10 matches and one with more than ten.

Comment: Thanks @ThorstenKettner!  One more question, will the results be the same every time I run the query?  I do NOT want this.  For example, if there are 20 matches I do not want the same ones every time and the same goes for non-matches.

Comment: It's arbitrary choices, not random ones. So, you are likely but not guaranteed to get the same rows when you run the query again. You would have to add another column opr expression (e.g. an ID) to the `ORDER BY` clause to guarantee a constant sort order. You could then use the `OFFSET` keyword to skip ten rows and get the next ten, etc.

Comment: Or, if you want it completely random, e.g. ten random rows (preferring matches) first, then ten other (or same) random rows (preferring matches again), etc., you'd add `, random()` to the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Thanks @thorstenkettner!!